# How to pass a string as command line argument for bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to pass a string as command line argument to a bash script;
Simply my bash script is:

```
>cat test_script.sh

for i in $*
do 
echo $i
done
```

I typed

> bash test_script.sh test1 test2 "test3 test4"

Output :

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Output I am expecting:

```
test1
test2
test3 test4
```

I tried with backslashes (test1 test2 "test3\ test4") and single quotes but I haven't got the expected result.

How do I get the expected output?

Comment: Aren't Output and expected Output same?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use:

```
for i in "$@"
do echo $i
done
```

or even:

```
for i in "$@"
do echo "$i"
done
```

The first would lose multiple spaces within an argument (but would keep the words of an argument together).  The second preserves the spaces in the arguments.

You can also omit the `in "$@"` clause; it is implied if you write `for i` (but personally, I never use the shorthand).

Answer (score -1):

Try use printf

```
for i in $* do $(printf '%q' $i) done
```

Comment: That won't work while you use `$*`; you have to use `"$@"`, explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: a fuller explanation might help